# Transparent background of UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

I programmed a UITextField to be rounded on the top left and right corners but the background of the textfield is now all black

[image]

```
let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "signupbackground.jpg")
self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
self.signupButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5

let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
rectShape.bounds = self.userEmailTextField.frame
rectShape.position = self.userEmailTextField.center
rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.userEmailTextField.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft , .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)).cgPath

self.userEmailTextField.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
//Here I'm masking the textView's layer with rectShape layer
self.userEmailTextField.layer.mask = rectShape
```

How do I make it so the top left/right corners are the same radius but the textfield is fully visible?

Answer (score 3):

You're setting the layer's background color to black:

```
self.userEmailTextField.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
```

Try `UIColor.clear.cgColor` instead, and you may want to set that *after* you draw the mask:

```
self.userEmailTextField.layer.mask = rectShape
self.userEmailTextField.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
```

Comment: Ok switch the order again?

Comment: I get the same thing

Comment: Alright you may need to draw the border over top afterwards rather than using a mask like that then

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0hkSwjNY That's the code now but its still the same

Comment: Fix it with: 
txfSearchField.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;